# Basis for the intersection of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, intersection-theory

Consider two subspaces $U=\{(a,b,c,d)|b-5c+d=0\}$ and $W=\{(a,b,c,d)|a=d\;,\; b=5c\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$.
Find  a basis and the dimension of $U \cap W$.

So what I have so far is that the intersection must contain vectors which exist in both subspaces so these vectors must meet both $b-5c+d=0$ and $a=d$, $b=5c$ which led me to the conclusion that the vectors in the intersection follow $b(5c)-5c+d(a)=0 \Rightarrow d(a) = 0$ : so vectors in the intersection are of the form $(0,5,1,0)$.

Is this a basis for the intersection, and if so is the dimension just $1$?

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you wrote as you don't use MathJaX, but it *seems to be* that your idea is correct...

Answer (score 0):

Choose basis $\;\{\,(1,1,0,-1)\,,\,\,(1,0,0,0)\,,\,\,(0,5,1,0)\,\;,\;\;\{\,(0,5,1,0)\,,\,\,(1,0,0,1)\,\}\;$ of$\;U,\,W\,$ resp., and now form a matrix with the above vectors as rows and reduce it. Whatever "vanishes" belongs to the intersection:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&\!-1\\1&0&0&0\\0&5&1&0\\0&5&1&0\\1&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&\!-1\\0&\!-1&0&1\\0&5&1&0\\0&5&1&0\\0&\!-1&0&2\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&\!-1\\0&\!-1&0&1\\0&0&1&5\\0&0&1&5\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

we can already see that only the fourth row is going to become all zedros in the next step, thus

$$U\cap W=\text{Span}\,\{\,(0,5,1,0)\,\}$$

which is your answer. Observe the above shows you a general way to attack these problems, as "seeing" the solution straighforward from the definition is, usually, much harder and not always will be possible to do it as you did it.

Comment: Can you please explain why your technique actually works?

Comment: @helios321 For a general set of vectors in coordinate form in some linear space of finite dimension, the above procedure tells you what vectors in that set are linearly dependents on others there. I took basis of $\;U\;$ and of $\;W\;$ and put the vectors together. We got that only one *common*  vector of both basis, namely $\;\{0,5,1,0)\;$, is lin. dependent on the other $\;4\;$ , which means that vector spans the common lin. space, i.e., the intersection, of $\;U,\,W\;$ . This works so fine because there's a common vector in both basis. Usually, it only gives the intersection's dimension.

Comment: so generally if there is no common basis vector, it does not give us a basis vectors for the intersection.  However the number of zero rows is still the dim of the intersection.  Why is this last part true?

Comment: @helios321 Because of $$\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U\cap W)$$ so when we take the vectors of *both* basis, we're in fact trying to find out what the **left hand side** above is. In our case, it was $\;4\;$, and since the first addends on the right are $\;3,\,2\;$ , we get that $\;\dim(U\cap W)=1\;$ ...and this much is true **always**